# using php guzzle for PUT with stream and parameters

Tags: php, rest, stream, guzzle

I'm trying to figure out how to implement the following REST PUT using Guzzle. I've tried using multipart and json, but I'm not sure what the syntax should be for having the parameters with a streamed xml file.

Can anyone help me translate this into a proper query? Below is what I tried so far, but it returns an error because it says the ProjectXML must be included.

[image]

```
$newUri = sprintf('%s/projects/%s/storage', $api_base, $testPid);
$newResp = $client->put($newUri,
    [
        'headers'         => [
            'Authorization' => sprintf("HubApi %s", $api_key),
        ],
        'multipart' => [
            [
                'name'     => 'ProjectXml',
                'contents' => file_get_contents("xml/$testPid.xml")
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'ProjectId',
                'contents' => $testPid
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'HubUserId',
                'contents' => "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx"
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'ProductId',
                'contents' => "$(package:ourcompany/ourproducttype)/products/ProductABC123"
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'ThemeUrl',
                'contents' => "$(package:ourcompany/ourproducttype)/themes/themename-white-Classic"
            ],

        ]
    ]
);
```

Response:

```
`400 Bad Request - Validation Error` response:
{"code":"RequestValidationError","message":"'Project Xml' should not be empty."}
```

Comment: Have you tried verifying that the `file_get_contents()` is outputting the correct content?

Comment: I tried it also with fopen("xml/$testPid.xml", 'r') - and yes, the file has the correct contents. It's the same file I downloaded from the same source with the ProductId and ThemeUrl changed. I'm trying to update some files on the cloud service with new product details.

Comment: The only other thing I would recommend is removing the non required fields, then getting your headers and multipart array separately before adding it to the Guzzle object. If necessary, try an external application to simulate a PUT request (like postman), to ensure that your data is in the correct format.